# How does include work in PHP

Tags: php, include, php-include

I have two files X.php and Y.php as shown below and I am not quite able to figure out what the include statement signifies. In both, these cases the code did not do what I expected it to do. So, I would like to know how it works.

**Scenario 1: Variable defined in Y is used in X**

***X.php***

```
<?php
include 'web/y.php';
echo $test;
?>
```

***Y.php***

```
<?php
$test =  'Hello World';
?>
```

**My Expectation:** Variable `$test` should be accessible in *X.php* after the include statement

**Scenario 2: Value printed in Y is used in X**

***X.php***

```
<?php
include 'web/y.php';
?>
```

***Y.php***

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

**My Expectation:** Hello World should be printed when *X.php* is accessed

Comment: What did you expect, and what did you get? You just said it didn't do what you expected.

Comment: *"I am not quite able to figure out what the include statement signifies"* - It means to "include a file inside the present called file". The manual is clear on this http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php *"The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file. "* --- I don't quite get the question. What is it you expect it to do and what are the present results you're getting? You may also want to read http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Qirel I have added my expectation of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Scenario 1: Variable defined in Y is used in X**
>
> **Scenario 2: Value printed in Y is used in X**

Both work exactly as you want, i.e. output `Hello World`.

If they didn't work for you, probably, you gave wrong path to `y.php`.

The directory structure must be as follows:

```
x.php
web/y.php
```

If you have these files in the same directory, then you shouldn't put `web/` in front of `y.php`.